# Ubuntu Karmic ignores .xinitrc

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 9.10 recently, and I can't get it to load my ~/.xinitrc when I log into Gnome.

Comment: This is a better candidate for http://superuser.com

Comment: It's hard to keep all the different sites straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a call in ~/.gnomerc that loads ~/.xinitrc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you log in using GDM or any other graphical login manager?
They usually ignore **.xinitrc** and read **.xsession** instead.

You could symlink **.xinitrc** to **.xsession** or the other way around to keep them synched:

```
ln -s .xinitrc .xsession
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ln -s .xinitrc .xsession ?

Comment: Hm, in this example, yes. Thanks for pointing it out.